# Deriving implications of a system of equalities and inequalities?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, inequality

Consider the system
$$
\begin{cases}
1=A+B=C+D\\
B\geq C
\end{cases}
$$
with $A,B,C,D$ positive.

Does the system imply that $A\leq D$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  The $1 = A + B$ has nothing to do with it, but if $A+B = C+D$, and $B \ge C$, then $C-B \le 0$, and so:

$$A = C + D - B = D + C - B \le D + 0 = D$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$D-A=D-A+(A+B)-(C+D)=B-C.$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $A > D$. We know $B \geq C$, so add these two inequalities, giving $A + B > C + D$, a contradiction.  Hence $A \leq D$.